# Managing multiple users in page

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I building one application in VB.Net that i have multiple drop downs

```
Date Received
Date Expired
Date send
Account Status
Remarks
```

In that Date Received drop down shows the Received date time and Date Expired date shows the Expired date time from database.

**Problem:**

If two user access the page at the same time. One user was changed the Received date and Expired date time. but another user can see the old received date and Expired date because that date fields are updated once the page is load. In that situation i need to give alert message like "Another user already changed the Received date and Expired date. please refresh your page". I don't know how to handle this situation.

Comment: Is this a winform or webform app?

Comment: @Mych This is webform application